# Browserify module dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I have:

**main.js**

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery');
var mainUI = require('./main-ui');

mainUI();
```

**main-ui.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
module.exports = function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement: 'bottom'
    });

    $('#sb_toggle').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('hide');
        $(this).toggleClass('show-sidebar');
    });
};
```

Am I right to assume that I have to require jquery in every single module I make?

Why wouldn't it simply work by requiring jquery in the main.js file so that all required modules after that line have $ available?

Answer (score 0):

Browserify doesn't work like that. Essentially every module is sandboxed in a IIFE.

This is do to the fact that jQuery uses the [UMD pattern](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/). As a result, when 
jQuery is used in a NodeJS environment **it does not expose global variables**

You can handle this in several ways:

- Use [factor bundle](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle)
- Use Browserify's "global" ( a reference to the browser window object ) object: global.$ = require( 'jquery' )
- Simply use jQuery the "classic" way be including it as a standalone library. 
  by using the "script" tag:

A fourth option requires a bit of repetition. Assuming you include your "main" module everywhere you need jquery, you can use the "main" to expose references to anything you need ( in this case, jquery ).

For example ( assuming file name is main-ui.js ):

```
// This is a how "main-ui" should look like
var $ = require( 'jquery' )

// ... Some business logic
function drawColor( color ) { ... } 

// Exposed members:
return {
    $: $,
    colorDraw: drawColor  
}
```

And this is how every module that needs jquery should look like:

```
var $( "../main-ui.js" ).$ // <-- Notice the path should be relative to the current working directory

// .. Use '$' like you always do.
```

Comment: how do I use it the classic way?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require("jquery");
```

This seems to work fine or is there something sinister I'm missing?

Comment: Forgot about global :( this is definitely another way!